# CSS resize font-size of word to fill screen

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

In [this small example](http://jsfiddle.net/yqY23/1/), I want `#bigWord` to have as large a font-size as possible, but still have all of the word visible in the viewport at one time. I'm thinking that I want to use [viewport-sized typography](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) such as `font-size: *x* vmin;`, but I'm not sure what value to use for `*x*`.

The word could have anywhere from 1-10 characters, and it's not a monospaced font. So, 'wwwwwwwwww' would have to be smaller than 'iiiiiiiiii' (extreme examples).

Any ideas?

Comment: @thirtydot, I think I must be misunderstanding the viewport percentage lengths, then.

Comment: No, you're not. I am. Chrome was playing a prank on me. This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/eWqVC/. Removing previous incorrect comment.

Comment: Nope just, kidding. I remember why I said "you need JavaScript" now. The part where you can have a variable number of characters. CSS can't help with that.

Comment: I read the article I liked more closely, and realized each vmin/vh/vw specifies the width of 1 individual character.